HERE Traffic API: How to Create a Network In Python From Flow Data
How can I create a networkx graph and feed the edges the flow data that I receive from real flow data in HERE API?
I tried to check the documentation, but the developer documentation is not clear on what to do. Here's a small segment of the data that I deceive. It doesn't contain any info on how a road is connected to another road.
I tried matching roads by getting a road network from the open street map and matching it by name, It works on some degree but that's not the best practice since some roads are have the same name etc.
